# Iterating over List of Objects inside another Object i have in the List

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

So i have structure like that

```
List<Object1> list1

class Object1{
   private List<Object2> list2
}
class Object2{
   private List<Object3> list3
}
```

And i need to get count of all Objects3 instances.
I am new to java-8 and streams so it's pretty confusing for me but i tried to do smth like that.

```
Integer count =
                list1
                .parallelStream()
                .reduce(0,(sum, q) -> q.getList2()
                        .forEach()
                        .reduce(0,(sum2, q2) -> sum2 + q2.getList3().size()));
```

Am i even close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't blame you, given that you're new to the stream API, but your approach is overcomplicated.

I'd personally go with this approach for simplicity & readability.

```
list1.stream() // Stream<Object1>
     .flatMap(s -> s.getList2().stream()) // Stream<Object2>
     .flatMap(s -> s.getList3().stream()) // Stream<Object3>
     .count(); // return the count of all Object3 instances
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need the *sum of the size* of the `list3` within each `Object2` instance, you can use `flatMapToInt` with a nested `mapToInt` to calculate the `sum` as:

```
int count = list1
        .stream()
        .flatMapToInt(obj1 -> obj1.getList2()
                .stream()
                .mapToInt(obj2 -> obj2.getList3().size()))
        .sum();
```